# Memory release has no effect in Three.js

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, three.js

I have a large number of objects in a scene, but I can not release the memory with following codes:

```
for (var i in all3DObj) {
    console.log("disposing");
    scene.remove(all3DObj[i]);
    all3DObj[i].geometry.dispose();
    if (all3DObj[i].material instanceof Array) {
        for (var j = 0; j < all3DObj[i].material.length; j++) {
            all3DObj[i].material[j].dispose();
            if (all3DObj[i].material[j].map) all3DObj[i].material[j].map.dispose();
        }
    } else {
        all3DObj[i].material.dispose();
        if (all3DObj[i].material.map) {
            all3DObj[i].material.map.dispose();
        }
    }
    all3DObj[i] = null;
}
```

How to release the memory effectively?

Comment: That looks pretty much alright, only addition: If you're using other textures (normalMap etc) you might need to dispose them manually as well. Are you 100% sure that there is not a reference to any of these objects anywhere else? Did you wait until the next full GC-run before measuring free'd memory? How do you measure the memory used?

Comment: There is still an open issue in `WebGLRenderer` that could cause your problem, see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/12464. Try to call `renderer.renderLists.dispose()` after your `for` loop.

Comment: you might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/33199591/1980846

Comment: OK, thank you very much! I will try it as soon as possible.