# Firefox does not clear memory when a refresh my Three.js based page

Tags: firefox, three.js, garbage-collection, webgl

I have been coding for an hour a web page in Three.js using Firefox as a browser. For some reason whenever I press refresh Firefox, it keeps increasing the memory. Doesn't have a garbage collector? When I see the memory from the tools, I see that only 74MB are dedicated to the web page. So the other 7000 MB are from previous sessions, I assume ???

[image]

Comment: Thats a good question, I always assume Firefox discarded everything on page refresh. Is it a hard refresh each time, or does your local host perform a “hot-reload”? Also, does this happen on other browsers as well?

Comment: You should do a similar test with an asset-heavy example: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_gltf and try to refresh the page a few times. Or try to visit several examples. If the memory consumption goes up and down, then its not a ThreeJS issue, but your dev environment’s. It’s probably not performing a true page refresh.

Comment: No, the size is not the problem. It is even worse in big files, the memory allocation rises even faster.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dispose properly the instances of `Material`, `Geometry`, `WebGLRenderer` and `scene`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55131538/three-js-how-to-correctly-dispose-a-scene-in-memory) is a well self-answered question on the topic, but the best for me (the one I use) is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152132/three-js-collada-whats-the-proper-way-to-dispose-and-release-memory-garbag)